Looking for Template for Paperback
I do not agree with the classification of my question as too unspecific. I asked for templates and specified what I need them for. I don't think that lecturing me that templates are not the right approach to solving my problem is an appropriate response. It may be that there are no suitable templates. Such a statement would be a reason to consider my question having been answered and to close it. However, I have not heard this statement so far.
--
I am looking for a good template for a paperback version of my LaTeX-text.
I find it extremely difficult to get to grips with KOMA. Templates would help me understand how to make adjustments to the layout.
I fail at such trivial things as setting the font size of titles in chapters and subchapters or the layout of headers and footers. Is there a collection of examples that show me how to make these and similar settings?

welcome! if you can provide some code for a minimal example and ask a specific question, people can show you how to change specific things. you can then ask another question about some other thing. but you would need to tell us what you want to do e.g. what do you want to change about the fonts or what do you want to alter about the headers and footers?

To set font sizes of chapters, section etc. see \setkomafont in the KOMA-Script user manuals. For the layout of headers and footers see the scrlayer-scrpage (and maybe the scrlayer) chapter in the same user manual. The manuals also contain lots of examples. Additional examples can be found here at the [tag:koma-script] related questions and in the KOMA-Script Wiki. If you need more help, please ask a specific question instead of a very broad+abstract.

"Templates would help me understand ..." Quite the opposite. The elaborated templates are mainly useful for not understanding what you are doing, and this is fine when all works out of the box "asis", or with minimal settings, but otherwise, it could be a nightmare. The best template the empty document, and then search the solution for each thing that you will need, and only add it if you understand it, step by step, until you obtain the desired format.

The first problem with your question is "good template". What is a good template for you? Must it be the same for me? I do not think so ... Second: Sometimes I teach LaTex and all people using templates they do not understand have a lot of problems! So really start with an empty document, start writing and add only that things you really need and understand to your document. Please see also the comment of @fran!

Some hints. // The better approach in this community would be to focus on one aspect, e.g. layout adjustments, AND presenting simplified KOMA code demonstrating your attempt or problem. So you may want to post a few such more focused questions. // However, the KOMA manual provides it all, see e.g p. 56ff. on font sizes https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script . In its index you’ll find many more on font sizes. // In some books introducing Latex there is also a short overview about KOMA. Also the web will provide introductions. BUT … what do you really need? Can only guess.

Here is a template for a paperback using KOMA-Script:
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\title{How to Make a Paperback}
\author{Me}
\date{2024-10-17}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}

For modifications like the size of the chapter headings or the formatting of page header and footer see the KOMA-Script manual, which is available in English and in German.
There is also several additional HowTo information available in the English or the German KOMA-Script wiki. Tags like koma-script, scrbook, scrreprt, scrartcl, typearea, scrlayer-scrpage etc. may also be useful to find other questions about how to change the formatting of several elements using KOMA-Script.
